# AS3 Closure Confusion

Tags: actionscript-3, closures

I have a small loop

```
var a:Array = [{name:Test1},{name:Test2},{name:Test3},{name:Test4}]
var b:GenericButton; //A pretty basic button component

for(var i:int = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  b = new GenericButton(a[i].name, function():void { trace(i) });
  this.addChild(b);
}
```

The function supplied to the GenericButton is executed when the button is pressed.

The problem I am having is that when the no matter what button I press the value of 4 (the length of the array) is always output.

How would I ensure that I trace 0 when the first button is pushed, 1 when the second is pushed, etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you can simply do:

```
var f:* = function():void { trace(arguments.callee.index) };
f.index = i;
b = new GenericButton(a[i].name, f);
```

Better still:

```
function createDelegate(obj:Object, func:Function):Function
{
    var f:* = function ():* {
        var thisArg:* = arguments.callee.thisArg;
        var func:* = arguments.callee.func;

        return func.apply(thisArg, arguments);
    };

    f.thisArg = obj;
    f.func = func;

    return f;
}
```

...

```
for (...) {
      b = new GenericButton(a[i].name,
          createDelegate({index: i}, function():void { trace(this.index) }));
}
```

And in some (most?) cases it would be even better if you created a separate class and passed `i` into the constructor.

Comment: Why do you use untyped var and untyped return argument? It should be `Function` and `void`.

Comment: I was sure `arguments.callee` was removed in AS3, is it?

Comment: @ValentinSimonov the return type of the function is actually unknown (depends on `func`, which is passed from outside). `f` is untyped because we need to stick `thisArg` and `func` onto it.

Comment: That's odd that Flash doesn't allow to set index on f if it is typed as `Function` since `Function` is dynamic.

Comment: @alxx `arguments.callee` is very much around. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/arguments.html

Comment: This solution worked very well, and did not require a change to the GenericButton class. There is another solution below with a good explanation of why this issue occurs.

Answer (score 1):

This is most basic error when using closures. You might be thinking that `i` is set when GenericButton is created. But closure just get direct link to variable `i` and uses this link when anonymous function is called. By this time, cycle is finished, and all links to `i` are pointing to same integer with value = 4.
To fix this, just pass value of `i` somehow - for example, as an additional argument to GenericButton constructor. In this case, a copy of `i` will be created on each step, with values of 0, 1, 2, 3 - just like you need.

```
...
b = new GenericButton(a[i].name, function(i:int):void { trace(i); }, i);
...
```

Store `i` in GenericButton and pass into function - this causes anonymous function to stop using context variable `i` (cycle counter) and forces it to use argument `i`.

Comment: This is also a good solution. However, it would require that I change GenericButton, where as the above solution does not require the change. The explanation from this solution is very good.

Answer (score 1):

Make a function that returns a function. Here's a FlexUnit test method that demonstrates it.

```
    [Test]
    public function closureWin():void
    {
        var functions:Array = [];
        var mkFn:Function = function(value:int):Function
        {
            return function():int
            {
                return value;
            }
        }

        var i:int;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            functions.push(mkFn(i));
        }

        var j:int;
        for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            assertEquals(j, functions[j]());
        }
    }
```

Here's a test method demonstrating the behavior you are seeing:

```
    [Test]
    public function closureFail():void
    {
        // basically to see if this works the same way in as3 as it does in javascript
        // I expect that all the functions will return 10

        var i:int;
        var functions:Array = [];
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            functions.push(function():int{return i});
        }

        var j:int;
        for each (var f:Function in functions)
        {
            assertEquals(10, f());
        }
    }
```